# SQL inserting rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, sql-insert

I have got an assignment. We have been given a table, MAIN_TABLE, which has a column patient_id as foreign key.

I need to make a separate table named patient which has patient_id as a primary key along with some other attributes such as name and address.

I did successfully create schema of this table. Now there is a serious problem I am facing. After creating this table I used insert statement to insert values for name and address from a dummy table.

Till this point everything works fine. However, the column patient_id is still empty rather I have set it to 0 by default.

Now the problem is that I need to get values into this column, patient_id, from the patient_id column of MAIN TABLE.

I can't figure out how do I do this? I did try to use:

```
UPDATE patient
SET patient_id=(select id from MAIN_TABLE)
```

BUT this gives me error that multiple rows returned which does make sense but what condition do I put in where clause then?

Comment: You just ask the question clear and give all the columns in the dummy table, and which order you have to insert the patient_id values in the dummy table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name                                                                                  I am using Sql and I need to copy some columns from dummy table and one from MAIN_TABLE

Comment: SQL is not a DBMS product, it's a query language.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange. How can there be a table `MAIN_TABLE` with a foreign key `patient_id` but the master table `patient` does not exist. Where do that `patient_id`s in `MAIN_TABLE` come from?

I suggest not to insert your data from a dummy table alone and then try to update it. But insert it with both - the `MAIN_TABLE` and the dummy table joined. If you can not join them. You would also not be able during the update.

So since i think they have no connected primary/foreign keys the only way to join them is using a good business key. Do you have a good business key?
You are talking about persons. So First Name, Last Name, Birth Day, Address often is good enough. But you have to think about it.

With your given data I can only give you some kind of meta insert statement. But you will get the point.

Example:

```
insert into patient (col1, col2, col3)
select 
  a.colA, 
  a.colF,
  b.colX
from 
  dummy_table a
    inner join MAIN_TABLE b on a.colN=b.colA and a.colM=b.colB
```

**And**: If `patient_id` is your primary key in `patient` you should ensure that it is even not possible to have duplicate values or `null` in this column. And you should use constraints to ensure your data integrity.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm